# Why ethernet always works 'out of the box' and wifi doesn't (in some or the other cases)?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, ethernet

I know of Broadcom and realtek based wifi adapters used to give pain in the neck because of their not easily available drivers. In some cases, you may have to try different drivers for the same adapter because one is
giving you sub-standard performance.
But my question is, why ethernet connection almost always seems to have support all the time? Are they not diverse enough and so it is easily possible to include support for all of them? I read somewhere that it was because of a single developer from BSD (openBSD ? ) who fixed the problem for once and for all. Something like that. Care to throw some light on that as well  if that's the case.

Comment: I'd say wireless authentication plays a relevant part here too.

Answer (score 3):

Wifi adapters often require firmware to be uploaded to the adapter by the operating system, and some distributions don’t include that firmware in their default installation images because it isn’t free software (*i.e.*, succinctly, it isn’t provided with source code in a form that’s modifiable by the user, with an appropriate license). This means that the wifi adapters in question can’t be used easily. This causes a lot of difficulty for users, and Debian for example is infamous in this respect (which has led to numerous discussions, *e.g.* [this recent long thread](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2021/01/msg00151.html)).

Ethernet adapters on the other hand typically *don’t* require such firmware uploads, and can therefore be used as-is. There are a few Ethernet adapters where this isn’t true, and they are as difficult to use as wifi adapters.

As far as hardware diversity goes, I suspect there’s as much on the Ethernet side as on the wifi side. But Ethernet adapters tend to have their drivers included in the kernel, whereas some wifi adapters rely on out-of-tree drivers which complicates matters further: the drivers have to be built for the kernel in use, and in secure boot environments, signed on top of that...

(Some distributions make exceptions for binary firmware; see [Fedora’s stance on the issue](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Licensing:Main#Binary_Firmware) for example.)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a simple, easy answer for why Ethernet drivers tend to be more reliable on Linux than Wi-Fi drivers, but there are a couple of reasons.

- Many servers use Ethernet cards and Linux servers are much more common than Linux desktops and laptops.  Large companies would refuse to buy servers with Brand A Ethernet adapters if Brand A had shoddy drivers in the kernel, and Brand A would lose out on a lot of money.
- The Ethernet standards do not change as frequently as Wi-Fi, which continually adds new security features and new speeds, so the lifetime of an adapter chip is longer, so it's easier to iron out all the bugs in a driver and fewer drivers need to be developed.
- Ethernet adapters usually work with just a driver and don't require firmware.  Firmware development and maintenance is a cost.  Because firmware can usually operate a Wi-Fi card in such a way as to violate regulatory compliance (and therefore the law), it is usually proprietary, and as such it is harder to share development with the open source community or distribute it as a distro.

Comment: "Linux servers are much more common than Linux desktops and laptops." Do you have some reference?

Comment: I don't have a citeable source, but that has been the case at every company I'm familiar with, who tend to have boatloads of Linux servers and comparatively few Linux laptops or desktops.  The actual number is probably unknowable, since nobody has to register their Linux installations.

Comment: Funnily enough, most Ethernet adapters that require firmware *are* used pretty much only in servers...

Comment: Out of curiosity, I went and did some digging. https://hostingtribunal.com/blog/linux-statistics/ @Quasímodo (It doesn't state it directly, but the numbers would indicate their statement is likely accurate - *if we ignore the mobile market and Android*.)

Comment: @KGIII My doubt is if the number of servers running Linux surpasses the number of desktops running Linux. If the quoted phrase means rather that the share of Linux among servers is greater than the share of desktops/laptops running Linux, I do find it very more likely.

Comment: If I did [the math](https://www.websitehostingrating.com/internet-statistics-facts/) right (and their numbers are truthful), there are roughly 44,000,000 Linux desktop users. In 2014, there were about 75,000,000 servers (I can't find newer numbers). So, it looks likely. There are a whole lot of servers out there. The 75 mil was only public-facing servers on the internet and is from 7 years ago.